# DXApplication could not found

Tags: c#, .net

I made DXApplication but as i ran it , it generated an error that DXAppliaction could not found. Can you help me. Here is attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: please try clean and build the solution.

Comment: You have a build error, as far as I can see.

Comment: Are you missing an assembly reference?

Answer (score 1):

That message is saying that the debugger cannot find the EXE file that it thought was just built and therefore cannot run it.

Someone else had this problem a while back. Turned out that their antivirus program (Avast) was automatically deleting the generated EXE file. Try disabling your antivirus program and rebuilding your app to see if the problem goes away. If it does, set your antivirus program to ignore your project's output directory, or change its settings globally to something more sane.

The other more obvious answer is that there's a problem during the build (i.e., a compiler or linker error) that is preventing the EXE from being generated. But if this were the case, Visual Studio should know that and not try to launch the EXE. Still worth a check, though, since your "Error List" visible in the screenshot indicates that you *do* have a compiler error:

> The type or namespace name 'DXApplication' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

You have probably forgotten to add a reference to your project for the library required to use DXApplication. Fix that, and do a "Rebuild All".